# akka: dedicated dispatcher or future?

Tags: scala, akka, dispatcher, future

I have a bunch of Actors (Akka 2) that need to communicate with a background system synchronously.

Is there something wrong with just having the Actors use a separate dedicated dispatcher and perform the processing synchronously like

```
def receive = {
  case Foo(foo) => sender ! getFooSynchronously(foo)
  case Bar(bar) => sender ! getBarSynchronously(bar)
}
```

or should I use futures like the following?

```
def receive = {
  case Foo(foo) => Future { getFooSynchronously(foo) } pipeTo sender
  case Bar(bar) => Future { getBarSynchronously(bar) } pipeTo sender
}
```

If I am not mistaken, using Futures would allow to ask the Actor for Foo and Bar in parallel and join the results, which is not possible with the synchronous approach. Taking into account that I don't need the parallel processing: is it more efficient to use a dedicated dispatcher and avoid the creation of the futures?

Comment: As long as you know that the former will *block* your `receive` method and your actor will not handle more messages until the synchronous call completes, it could be a perfectly valid decision.

Comment: I agree that using a separate dispatcher to 'firewall' off these synchronous/blocking actors is a good idea.  You want to avoid blocking behavior in the main dispatcher for the actor system, but this approach is okay when you have actors that simply must block.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A dedicated dispatcher is in order either way, if you ultimately need more concurrent `getSynchronously()` operations than default dispatcher max pool size.

But to your question I agree with @rob-starling , both are fine & have their uses.